# How to use android.support.v8.renderscript for renderscript

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm using intellij idea and I want to try renderscript. I read everywhere that I should use  android.support.v8.renderscript instead of android.renderscript. I have a big problem with this because when I want to create a new ScriptC_???(mRS) it demands a android.renderscript.RenderScript variant(mRS) and I can't find a constructor with the other packet RenderScript version. It seem that in the automaticly generated files, it uses that package too(android.renderscript). If I use the android.renderscript.RenderScript there then I have to use everywhere else.

How could I make it to use the support.v8 package?

Comment: No, support `ScriptC` constructor uses  `android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript` object. Please check if you are using the right import.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I created an asd.rs file and from that it generated a ScriptC_asd file in that file there is only 2 constructor and both needs a android.renderscript.RenderScript. In that file there is a android.renderscript.* import but I can't change that

Comment: If you correct your imports to android.support.v8.renderscript, and clean your project, imports in the generated script will also be corrected. Try it out. Then you also have to check the dependencies using project.property file in Eclipse OR check your gradle files if you are using in Android Studio Gradle project.

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena as I wrote I'm using IDEA, cleaning the project doesn't help I've put renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=18.1.0 everywhere I could

Comment: I have used this in my projects: see if it helps. They say use the latest API.    renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=19.0.3

Comment: @AbhinavSaxena I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't make it work :( I donwnloaded android studio.. it was hard to set up gradle but there I could compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the question on the IDEA forum and I got this answer:

Unfortunatelly Renderscript support mode is not supported for old-style IntelliJ projects. It is now available for Gradle-based (Android Studio style) projects only.